(runtime error 424)a macro that that can solve this
when I run this it keeps on showing (runtime error 424 object required). please help me correct this.
Sub Nextmonth()
If ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = 12 Then
    Exit Sub
Else:
    Range("A3").Value = Range("A3").Value + 1
    DLANDINV.Columns("B:NK").Hidden = True
    DLANDINV.Range(Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 - 29), Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 + 1)).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
Sub previousMonth()
If ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = 1 Then
    Exit Sub
Else:
    Range("A3").Value = Range("A3").Value - 1
    DLANDINV.Columns("B:NK").Hidden = True
    DLANDINV.Range(Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 - 29), Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 + 1)).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub

I tried changing the name of the sheet but I can't find the error yet. am expecting that my problem will be solved. and even correction on the code so that i can be able to run it.
